# Create observable for each item in list and combine their results

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have the following two `Single` functions:

```
fun getStrings(): Single<List<String>> {
    return Single.just(listOf("a", "a.b", "a.b.c"))
}

fun getStringParts(s: String): Single<List<String>> {
    return Single.just(s.split("."))
}
```

I want to combine them in a way that results in a `Map<String, List<String>` where the `key` is the result of the first function and the `value` is the result of the second function for each `String`, so

```
["a":["a"], "a.b":["a", "b"], "a.b.c":["a", "b", "c"]]
```

I use the first function, receive a `List` of `String`s, but can't wrap my head around

- how to create an observable for each String in the `List`
- combine them
- combine their results into a `Map`

Comment: You mean like `fromIterable` followed by `toMap` with a value selector performing the split + toList?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getStrings()
       .flattenAsFlowable { it }
       .flatMapSingle { s -> getStringParts(s).map { parts -> s to parts } }
       .toMap({ it.first }, { it.second })
```

This returns type `Single<MutableMap<String, List<String>>>`.

I hope everything is clear but if you have some doubts feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3):

```
val result = getStrings()
    .flattenAsObservable { it }         // Turn the list into a stream of items
    .flatMapSingle { key ->             // Take each item
        getStringParts(key)             // Get its parts
            .map { value ->
                key to value            // Combine key and value
            }
    }                                   // You now have a stream of pairs
    .toMap({ it.first }, { it.second }) // Build the map
    .blockingGet()

println(result)                         // {a=[a], a.b=[a, b], a.b.c=[a, b, c]}
```

Comment: Yeah. Looks like we came up with the same answer :) I guess that gives it some extra merit!